# AngularJs call a scoped directive in iteself with ng-repeat doesn't take the new scope of the child

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

The problem is that i have called Directive1 in same Directive1 using ng-repeat , and the directive11 has a value in scope , but when calling the nested same directive with the new value, it seems that take the first value.

i tried to call the same directive inside a ng-repeat of the dirctive

in html i have this:

```
<accordion close-others="true">
    <node function="functionCtrller(item)"
          ng-repeat="item in list"
          ng-model="item">
    </node>
</accordion>
```

in my directive definition i have:

```
myApp.directive('node', function($compile) {
return {
    restrict : 'E',
    terminal : true,
    scope : {
      node : '=ngModel',            
      function: '&function'
    },
    link : function($scope, $element) {
      if (angular.isArray($scope.node.children) && $scope.node.children.length > 0) {    
        $element.append('<accordion close-others="true"><node function="function(item)" ng-repeat="item in node.children" ng-model="item"></node></accordion>');
      }else{
      //....
      }    
      $compile($element.contents())($scope);
    } //end_link_directive
}; //end_return_directive
```

there isn't errors , only the new call of the function doesn't take the new item from the ng-repeat

Comment: The `ng-model` attribute instantiates the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController). If the component does not use the ngModel controller, it should use another name for that attribute.

Comment: i chnaged the ng-model to node, but same problem, the function took alwayse the first item , but if i tried to print the item.name, it appeared correctlly, only on the function isn't the new item

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link, it does a great job of explaining how to do what you're trying to do: https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-3-isolate-scope-and-function-parameters

A quick break down is:

```
<!-- Passing in the function with the outer item object passed -->
<node function="functionController(item)" ...>
```

And then inside you're doing:

```
<!-- Inner node passing the function which it was passed -->
<node function="function(item)" ...>
```

But this is just calling the outer function without passing the appropriate information down through the directive scope function.  What you want is something like this, where the inner directive knows what parameters need to be passed to it.

```
<!-- Please call the outer function using the parameter name item with my value item-->
<node function="function({item:item})" ... >
```

In the examples on the page, both take advantage of not using the real passed scope function but instead an inner function.  For example:

```
<node function="doFunction(item)" ...>

$scope.doFunction(item) { 
    $scope.function({item: item}); 
}
```